# OpenCV: Pipeline have not been created

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

```
[ WARN:0] global /build/opencv/src/opencv-4.5.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

The above error occurs when I run the following openCV related code.

```cpp
VideoCapture cap;

if(!cap.open(0)) { // error occurs here
     std::cout << "could not open camera" << std::endl;
}

Mat* frame = new Mat();
cap >> *frame;

imwrite(filename, *frame);
```

This started happening after I migrated to using a `CMakeLists.txt`, so here is that as well.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(opencv_webcam)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(opencv_webcam driver.cpp capture.cpp capture.h)

set(OpenCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_highgui opencv_imgcodecs)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

The only other instance I could find of this happening was in python, so im not sure if that applies here.

I was able to run a different project using

```
 g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename demo.cpp .cpp` demo.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

so I know opencv is set up properly. Any ideas on why this happens?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Which **exact line** of your code causes the given warning? Is `filename` is **relative** or **absolute** path? (CMake places executables not into the source directory). Also, variable `OpenCV_LIBS` is normally set by `find_package(OpenCV)` call and one needn't to set it manually. If you want to use specific OpenCV libraries then pass appropriate `COMPONENTS` option to the `find_package` (see e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196846/3440745)).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have marked the line in the question